# Trouble with a responsive menu and jQuery's slideToggle

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a responsive navigation menu and I'm having trouble getting the nav items to become visible upon calling jQuery's slideToggle(). The menu items (.nav_item) collapse appropriately, and then become invisible when the viewport is <640px, the first menu item (#nav_menu) "Menu" then becomes the only item visible. Upon clicking, I'd like the buttons to reappear and slide down below the menu button. When I click, however, nothing happens and the menu items remain invisible. If I take out `display: none !important;` from the menu items, they successfully toggle (but are visible the whole time). Does anyone know what's going wrong? Thanks.

CSS (Compass):

```
#navUL {

    @include background-image(linear-gradient($blue_dark, $blue_light));
    text-align: center;
}

#navUL li {

    a:link, a:visited {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 0 25px 0 25px; 
    }
    a:hover {
        @include background-image(linear-gradient($red_dark, $red_light));
    }
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#nav_menu {
    display: none !important;   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    #nav_menu {
        display: inline !important;
    }

    .nav_item {
        display: none !important;
    }

    #navUL li {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IE]>
      <link href="/stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <img src="top_banner.jpg">
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul id="navUL">
                <li id="nav_menu"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="nav_item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="main">

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#nav_menu').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.nav_item').slideToggle('slow');
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was basically just a [specificity issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Even though jQuery's `.slideToggle()` method adds inline styling, it still wasn't having an effect when the screen size was less than `640px` because you were using `!important`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
  .nav_item {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

More specifically, the above styling in your media query was overwriting the styling added by jQuery:

```
<li class="nav_item" style="display: list-item;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

To solve this, remove all instances of `!important` in your stylesheet and re-structure the styling with the specificity issues in mind. If I were you, I would avoid using `id`'s like this. Simple classes would suffice and help avoid future issues like this. Without *changing* any HTML, though, this would work:

```
#navUL #nav_menu {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #navUL #nav_menu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #navUL .nav_item {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Since you're already using jQuery, use the [resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) to remove the jQuery styling when the screen size wider than `640px`.

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 640) {
        $('.nav_item').css('display','');
    }
}).resize();
```

This should take care of everything. Take a look at [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ2f6/).